# Automate AWS deployment for new customers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, automation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, backup

As I'm following a multi-instance deployment strategy opposed to a multi-tenant, I'm deploying my entire infrastructure again for every new customer. This results in a lot of work as I have to

- Deploy a new API instance on Elastic Beanstalk + env variables
- Deploy a new webapp instance via s3
- Deploy a new file storage via s3
- Deploy a new backup file storage via s3
- Setup a new data pipeline backing up the file storage to the backup bucket
- Mapping the API and web app instance to a new customer-specific URL (e.g. `mycustomer.api.mycompany.com` and `mycustomer.app.mycompany.com`) via Route 53 + CloudFront
- ...

Is there a way to automate all of this deployment? I've looked into CodeDeploy by AWS but that doesn't seem to fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS tool that you can use to build infrastructure again and again is **CloudFormation**. We call this technique Infrastructure as a Code (IaaC). You can also use Terraform if you don't want to use AWS Specific tool.

You can use either YAML or JSON to define the template for your infrastructure. 
And, you'll be using Git to do templates change management.

Watch this reinvent [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01hy48R9Kr8&t=46s) to clear the whole picture.